# How to change the "no image" icon on a User Profile

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, user-profile

How to change the no image icon in user profile to some other default image when no image is uploaded in SharePoint 2013?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the image in layout folder!

Path:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

There you find four placeholder pictures

- personplaceholder.32x32x32.png
- personplaceholder.48x48x32.png
- personplaceholder.96x96x32.png
- personplaceholder.200x150x32.png

Replace this pictures with your customized pictures. Be sure, that you do that on all WFEs in your Farm!

Comment: And keep in mind they can be overwritten when you're updating your farm...

Comment: Just needed to use this today. The "48" is replaced with "42", at least in 15.0.4849.1000 :)